# APIs to create a custom issue list on Magit Forge?

Tags: magit, forge

Using Magit Forge, I'd like to organize a list of open issues by assignee.  Ideally I'd like to display them in groups by assignee, but I'd settle for a single list if the assignee were added to the display of each issue.

I started poking around the code, and I've just bumped into a lot of undocumented functions, like `forge-insert-topics`, `closql--remake-instance`, and so on.  Is there a reasonably small set of functions I can master to create a custom display of issues?  Or should I pay attention to my feelings of You Are Not Meant To Mess With This?